# invert the triangular coin setting in minimum no of steps

Tags: number-theory

Some coins are arranged in such a order that 1 coin is at the top,2 coins at the second row, 3 coins at the third and so on. In a single step we can displace a coin from its original place to another place. What is the least no of steps to invert the total arrangement? Can you provide a general formula for an arrangement having n rows.

I have found a formula that 
$$\min\Big(k (k+1)+\frac{(n-2k-1)(n-2k)} 2\Big)$$
$K\leq\frac{n-1}2$ when $n$ is odd,
$K\leq\frac n 2 - 1$ when $n$ is even.

Is this sequence any established sequence?

Comment: Do you know the answer for small numbers of coins?

Comment: What does "another place" mean, and what does "invert" mean?

Comment: Yeah,For 1 row it is 0, for 2 rows it is 1, for 3 it 2, for 4 it is 3, for 5 it is 5..

Comment: Sorry, if you bound the setting by a triangle , invert the triangle. and another place means pick a coin and put it on another row in the extreme left or right.

Comment: I tried to format your formula, could you check I got it right? If so, the formula appears to be badly written, since it seems you're taking the minimum of a single number.

Comment: It is minimum of the numbers where k takes the value from 1 to (n-1)/2 or from 1 to (n/2)-1

Answer (score 0):

From observation you can see that, For 1 row it is 0, for 2 rows it is 1, for 3 it is 2, for 4 it is 3, for 5 it is 5, for 6 it is 7.

The formula is:
FLOOR(n*(n+1)/6), where n is the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples for $2 \leq n \leq 7,$ in which the black circles represent coins that do not move, the white circles with red Xs represent spots that coins are moved from, and the plain white circles represent spots that coins are moved to:

[image]

From these examples a pattern emerges. We will move coins from a small triangle of coins in each of the three corners of the large triangle.
(When $n < 4,$ some of the "small triangles" contain no coins.)
We want the sizes of the small triangles to be as equal as possible, because the sum of the numbers of coins along the "edges" of the three small triangles
is always $n - 1$ but the number of coins in each small triangle grows with the square of the number of coins along an edge.
(Alternatively, see what happens if we shift the end-position triangle by one "spot" to make one of the small triangles exceed another by $2$ or more: we always increase one triangle by more coins than the decrease in the other triangle.)

So we always have one of the following conditions, where $m$ is the number of coins along one edge of the smallest "small" triangle:

$$
n = \begin{cases}
m + m + m + 1         &&& n \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
m + m + (m+1) + 1     &&& n \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
m + (m+1) + (m+1) + 1 &&& n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

The number of coins in a triangle with $m$ coins along edge edge is
$\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ and 
the number of coins in a triangle with $m+1$ coins along edge edge is
$\frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}$, so the total number of coins moved in each case is

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
3\frac{m(m+1)}{2}             &&& n \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
m(m+1) + \frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2} &&& n \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
\frac{m(m+1)}{2} + (m+1)(m+2) &&& n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

The three cases correspond to your formula as follows:

- Case $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$: Let $k = n - 2k - 1 = \frac13(n - 1) = m.$
- Case $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$: Let $k = \frac13(n - 2) = m$; then $n - 2k - 1 = m+1.$
- Case $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$: Let $k = \frac13 n = m+1$; then $n - 2k - 1 = m.$

Note that for $n \geq 6,$ it is always the case that 
$k \leq \frac13n \leq  \frac n2 - 1 < \frac{n-1}2,$
and for each of the cases $1 \leq n \leq 5$ you can individually confirm
that these formulas produce $k \leq\frac{n-1}2$ for odd $n$ 
and $k\leq\frac n2 - 1$ for even $n$,
so the limits you put on $k$ in your formula will always include the value of $k$ that really minimizes the number of coins moved.

Now let's try to see if there's a simpler version of this formula.

When $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ we set $m = \frac13(n - 1),$ so $m +1 = \frac13(n+2),$
and then
$$f(n) = 3\frac{m(m+1)}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{6} = \frac{n^2 + n - 2}{6}.$$

When $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ we set $m = \frac13(n - 2),$ so $m +1 = \frac13(n+1)$
and $m +2 = \frac13(n+4),$ and then
$$f(n) = m(m+1) + \frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}
 = \frac{(n-2)(n+1)}{9} + \frac{(n+1)(n+4)}{18}= \frac{n^2 + n}{6}.$$

When $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3,$ we set $m = \frac13(n - 3),$ so $m +1 = \frac13 n$
and $m +2 = \frac13(n+3),$ and then
$$f(n) = \frac{m(m+1)}{2} + (m+1)(m+2)
 = \frac{(n-3)n}{18} + \frac{n(n+3)}{9}= \frac{n^2 + n}{6}.$$

Note that in the case $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ we have that
$n^2 + n \equiv 2 \pmod 6$, 
so $f(n) = \left\lfloor \frac16(n^2 + n)\right\rfloor,$
and in the other two cases $n^2 + n \equiv 0 \pmod 6$, 
so again $f(n) = \left\lfloor \frac16(n^2 + n)\right\rfloor.$
This proves the claim made in an earlier answer that
$f(n) = \left\lfloor \frac16(n^2 + n)\right\rfloor.$